# Yarn adding issue

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

How would I install every package in package.json without have to type yarn add [ name ] like a million times? I just want to install all the packages at one time. How would I do it?

Comment: Just "yarn install", I recommend reading the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much!